How to align row to the bottom of the height unconstrained card in flutter?
I have an "infinite vertical scroll" with unconstrained height of the card. The only constraint is set for the image and all other elements shrink/expand to the remaining size. Text lines can expand max to 3 lines and title can expand max to 2 lines. So, the height of the text part might vary heavily: from 2 lines (1 line title + 1 line description) to 5 lines (2 lines title + 3 lines description).
Is there any possibility to align the row with the price and "Grab" button to the bottom of the card?
I've already tried all possibly align / stack / ... solutions with no luck unless I set a constant height of the card which I don't want to do.
Please, check image to see what I'm trying to achieve.

Update: adding some code that I have currently as asked (removed irrelevant code like styling)
Infinite scroll definition:
      ...
      builderDelegate: PagedChildBuilderDelegate<Deal>(
        itemBuilder: (context, deal, index) => Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: DealRow(deal: deal)
        ),
    ...


DealRow:
return GestureDetector(
  ...
  child: Container(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            // item image
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width * layoutConstants.dealImageWidthFraction,
              height: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width * layoutConstants.dealImageWidthFraction,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                image: DecorationImage(
                    // We keep Box.fit cover in inverted colors so the white image background on dark container background looks homogenous
                    image: NetworkImage(deal.imageUrl), fit: BoxFit.contain,
                ),
    ...
            ),
    // item details
            Expanded(child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    deal.title,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    maxLines: 2,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8),
                  Text(
                    deal.description,
                    maxLines: layoutConstants.maxDescriptionLines,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                  Stack(
                    children: [
                      Container(height: 50, alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, child:
                        PriceRow(deal: deal),
                      ),
                      Container(alignment: Alignment.centerRight, child:
                        TextButton(
                          child: Text(layoutConstants.size == LayoutSize.large ? "Grab a Deal" : "Grab", style: TextStyle(color: AppColor.primarySoft),),
...
)

PriceRow:
return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        if (deal.originalPrice != null && deal.originalPrice! > 0) Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 4),
            child: Text(
                formatCurrency.format(deal.originalPrice),
            )
        ),
        Container(
          // margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2, bottom: 8),
          child: Text(
            formatCurrency.format(deal.resultingPrice),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );


does it mean that the height of entire row is fixed at height: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width * layoutConstants.dealImageWidthFraction,?

That's the height of the image only

so if image height is 200 and combined height of title + text is 300 then the card should expand to 300, but if combined height of title + text is 100 then the card height should be 200? in other words: height = max(image height, combined height of title + text) ?

@pskink Yes, something like this, but, I don't know how to achieve this

I assume your title description and price part is wrapped with Column. Additionally, wrap title and desc with Column. Add parent Column widget MainAxisAlignmnet.spaceBetween.
Final structure should be like this:
Column (
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children:[
    Column(
      children: [
        Title(),
        Description(),
      ],
       
    ),
    PriceWidget(),
  ] 
)

If you share a code snippet, i can help better
***updated
After you share code, adding height of the image to the Expanded Container, and also adding Spacer between, desc and Stack will solve the issue.
Expanded(child: Container(
height: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width * layoutConstants.dealImageWidthFraction,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),

.....
 Text(
 deal.description,
 maxLines: layoutConstants.maxDescriptionLines,
 overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
),
const Spacer(),
Stack(
   children: [
     Container(height: 50, alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, child:
                        PriceRow(deal: deal),
                      ),


Thank you for your reply @pred_910255. Please, check the question, I've updated it with the code that is used in my project

The issue is specifically with unconstrained height. If I put height constraint then it works as it is but I don't want / can't put a height constraint. In your solution, if my text takes more height than the height of the image then I would have an overflow. So, I cannot "pre-compute" the needed height of the card

Try the hierarchy below for desired list view row item structure. Hope it helps
          Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.abc, size: 50),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text('title'),
                              Text('subtitle'),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                children: [Text('price1'), Text('price2')],
                              ),
                              Text('Grab'),
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ));

